# Libgdx 2d floor Animation

Tags: libgdx

I'm building Runner Game.
 Ground Class.

```
public class Ground extends Actor {

private Texture texture;
private ArrayList<Vector2> groundLocations;
private float speed;
private float cameraLeft, cameraRight;
private int textureWidth;


public Ground() {
    this.cameraRight = Const.GAME_WIDTH + Const.GAME_MARGIN;
    this.cameraLeft = 0 - Const.GAME_MARGIN;
    texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("ui/ground.png"));
    groundLocations = new ArrayList<Vector2>();
    init();
}

public void setSpeed(float speed) {
    this.speed = speed;
}

private void init() {

    textureWidth = texture.getWidth();
    float currentPosition = cameraLeft;
    while (currentPosition < cameraRight) {

        Vector2 newLocation = new Vector2(currentPosition, 0);
        groundLocations.add(newLocation);
        currentPosition += textureWidth;
    }

}

public int getFloorHeight() {
    return texture.getHeight();
}


@Override
public void act(float delta) {
    super.act(delta);
    int size = groundLocations.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        Vector2 location = groundLocations.get(i);
        location.x -= delta * speed;
        if (location.x < cameraLeft) {

            location.x = findMax().x + textureWidth;
        }
    }

}

private Vector2 findMax() {
    return Collections.max(groundLocations, new Vector2Comparator());
}


@Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
    super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
    for (Vector2 location : groundLocations) {
        batch.draw(texture, location.x, location.y);
    }
}




public void dispose() {
    if (texture != null)
        texture.dispose();
}
```

}

- Ground Texture is 128x128
- GAME_WIDTH = 1024f
- GAME_MARGIN = 250f
- speed = changes.

While the ground is moving according to Speed and FPS. (Speed * delta)
Problem is : There are always Gaps between ground Textures. after certain Movement
function findMax finds the texture with the biggest X 
any help would be Appreciated.

Solution:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        Vector2 location = groundLocations.get(i);
        if (location.x < cameraLeft) {
            location.x = findMax().x + textureWidth;
        }
        location.x -= delta * speed;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are getting gaps between the textures.

This is usually caused by floating point rounding errors and can usually be solved by using a texture packer to pack your images with padding.

Another possible fix is to change your texture filtering to NEAREST which basically uses the pixel nearest the point supplied.

Another possible fix is to limit your camera to INT positions which will remove floating point rounding all together.

Comment: Thank you for Answer i just replaced the location of check and it works...